# Preg_replace a string contains Forward slash in between

Tags: php, regex, laravel, preg-replace

i want to replace word contains forward slash this is the string 'Parziale/Finale'

i try preg_replace('/Parziale/Finale/','someword'); and didn't work it returns

preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'F'

and i have try the Delimiter ~ and # and also didn't work

Comment: Escape it using a backslash \

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add backslash before the /Finale

```
preg_replace('/Parziale\/Finale/','someword',$subject);
```

Comment: it works thank you and i wanna ask what if the string is Parziale\/Finale how to replace it

Comment: Parziale(\\\)\/Finale